# What is the difference between single and double action revolvers?

Tags: terminology, guns

Some revolvers are single action and some are double action, what exactly is the difference between the two types?

Comment: Lets move this discussion to meta: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/should-we-revisit-or-enforce-that-pistols-are-off-topic

Comment: I think this question is not on-topic for TGO, but that it could be made to be on-topic, so I am not going to VTC now.  If the Q stated the difference, and then asked what difference the difference would make in a, or several, TGO situation(s), then it would be on-topic.  For example, what kind would you want as defense against a large aggressive animal?  Probably you'd want a rifle or shotgun, but adding this aspect would provide a fig leaf to make it a TGO question.

Comment: @ab2 Under that logic, we would close this question outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/… and in fact it was closed for that reason, but as you will notice, it was just reopened

Comment: I think this stack is the most appropriate seeing as there is not a gun/shooting specific stack, also most gun enthusiasts are also outdoorsy type people generally speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TDLR : Single actions only fire the revolver, double actions both cock the hammer and fire.**

The way that revolvers work is that each time it is fired, the cylinder must be rotated and the hammer cocked so that it can be dropped onto the primer to fire the bullet.

To do this with a **single action revolver the user has to manually cock the hammer** back before pulling the trigger while pulling the trigger on a **double action revolver cocks the hammer and then fires the revolver** by dropping the hammer onto the primer.

The downside of not having to manually cock the hammer with a double action is that the the trigger pull is much heavier and that leads one to be less accurate.

Most double action revolvers however do have the ability to manually cock the hammer for extra accuracy.

Double action revolvers that lack the ability to manually cock the hammer are called **double action only**.

In addition there are a few double action revolvers such as the [Webley–Fosbery Automatic Revolver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webley%E2%80%93Fosbery_Automatic_Revolver) where the recoil is used to rotate the cylinder and cock the hammer to avoid the heavy trigger pull.

Answer (score -1):

Striker-fired pistols too, can be either "double action" or "single action." Usually the first shot in a magazine will require you to manually chamber the round, after which a pistol is then "single action." In cases where you don't manually chamber the round, the trigger pull is a longer, heavier, double action pull.

Comment: The question is limited to revolvers, so this doesn't answer the question

Comment: I think the answer is related enough that we can still appreciate and upvote it.

Comment: This answer is unclear. A double action handgun won't chamber a round, you have to rack the slide. The answer could be interpreted to think that it would.

Comment: @whatshisname Not just "could be interpreted to think", rather, this answer expressly states that is the case. Notice the "In cases where you don't manually chamber the round, the trigger pull is a longer, heavier, double action pull." That is, it states that the trigger pull will indeed chamber a round, similar to the revolvers in question. I was not aware that there were any such pistols with this capability, but it is certainly possible. Perhaps Gear Lobo can provide an example such a model.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh This would have made a fine comment and probably fit the comment limit. If it was a comment, I would hope it got edited into the question and/or your answer... since it should end up there anyway, perhaps it's moot: should Gear Lobo follow the rules to a tee, comment, hope you edit, and make your answer more generic and therefore better; or should he be able to side-step the rules a bit to be able to take the credit himself in an answer that doesn't technically answer but is essentially equivalent to what should have happened? I don't know.

Comment: @Aaron So I just asked the corresponding q&a and while this answer would answer that question and not this one, it would still be incorrect.

Comment: Vote to close: Neither "magazine" NOR 'manually chamber the round' apply to revolvers.

Comment: @Aaron See this proposal https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102381/weapons?referrer=rI1aSg1vumLOAZl60SdIxw2